Unable to Establish Connection from Node.js Application to Remote MySQL Database on NameCheap via SSH Tunnel
I'm having trouble setting up a connection from my Node.js application to a remote MySQL database hosted on NameCheap. I've tried multiple approaches, but nothing seems to work.

What I've tried so far:
1. Standard Connection Attempt:
Initially, I attempted to connect directly using the mysql package in Node.js, but the connection was refused. I suspect this is due to remote access restrictions on the database.
2. SSH Tunnel:
I set up an SSH tunnel to the NameCheap server using the tunnel-ssh package and attempted to connect through it. Unfortunately, this also failed. Here is a simplified version of the code I used:
import { Sequelize } from 'sequelize';
import { config } from 'dotenv';
import { createTunnel, ForwardOptions, ServerOptions, SshOptions, TunnelOptions } from 'tunnel-ssh';
import mysql2 from 'mysql2';

config();

const isProduction = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production';

let sequelize: Sequelize;

if (isProduction) {
  // SSH tunnel configuration
  const tunnelOptions: TunnelOptions = {
    autoClose: true,
  };

  const sshOptions: SshOptions = {
    host: process.env.SSH_HOST!,
    port: Number(process.env.SSH_PORT),
    username: process.env.SSH_USER!,
    password: process.env.SSH_PASSWORD!
  };

  const serverOptions: ServerOptions = {
    host: '127.0.0.1'
    port: 3307,
  };

  const forwardOptions: ForwardOptions = {
    dstAddr: process.env.DB_HOST!,
    dstPort: Number(process.env.DB_PORT),
  };

    const sequelize = new Sequelize(
        process.env.DB_NAME!,
        process.env.DB_USER!,
        process.env.DB_PASSWORD!,
        {
          host: '127.0.0.1',
          port: 3306,
          dialect: 'mysql',
          dialectModule: mysql2,
          logging: false,
        }
      );

  createTunnel(tunnelOptions, serverOptions, sshOptions, forwardOptions)
    .then(([server]) => {
      sequelize
        .authenticate()
        .then(() => {
          console.log('Database connection has been established successfully.');
        })
        .catch((dbError: Error) => {
          console.error('Unable to connect to the database:', dbError);
        });
    })
    .catch((error: Error) => {
      console.error('SSH tunnel connection error:', error);
    });
} else {
  sequelize = new Sequelize(
    process.env.DB_NAME!,
    process.env.DB_USER!,
    process.env.DB_PASSWORD!,
    {
      host: process.env.DB_HOST,
      port: Number(process.env.DB_PORT),
      dialect: 'mysql',
      dialectModule: mysql2,
      logging: false,
    }
  );

  sequelize
    .authenticate()
    .then(() => {
      console.log('Database connection has been established successfully.');
    })
    .catch((error: Error) => {
      console.error('Unable to connect to the database:', error);
    });
}

export default sequelize;

When I run this code, the SSH tunnel connection is not established correctly and the MySQL connection fails with a timeout or connection refused error.
3. Contacted NameCheap Support:
I reached out to NameCheap support for assistance. They confirmed that my SSH credentials and MySQL details are correct, but they couldn't provide further help on setting up the connection from Node.js.
Additional Information:
My Node.js environment is running locally on my machine. But I want to deploy it so that it will be used for my project and that is why I need an online mysql database.
I can SSH into the NameCheap server without issues using the same credentials.
Question:
What could be the reason my Node.js application is failing to connect to the MySQL database even after setting up an SSH tunnel? Are there any common pitfalls or additional configurations I might be missing when connecting Node.js to a remote MySQL database on NameCheap?

Also if there is a totally different and better way connection to a remote mysql database via SSH tunnel with Node.JS, please feel free to suggest!
Any advice or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!
I tried setting up a connection from my Node.js application to a remote MySQL database hosted on NameCheap using an SSH tunnel. I expected the application to connect to the database successfully, but it failed, resulting in either a timeout or a "connection refused" error. Despite the SSH tunnel using correct credentials, the connection could not be established.
